# How do I get back a window in the interface?

Tags: texturing

In one rig I have this but in the other I don't.

[image: In one rig I have this but in the other I dont, any help!?!]

Well basically I was doing a minecraft gfx when I accidentaly deleted this bar thing, could anyone help get it back?!

Answer (score 1):

Click here:
[image]

Until you see this icon. It's called the outliner.

[image]